# Bypass SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 10 go limit

Tags: sql-server

The limit of 10 GB is reached and different constraints force to circumvent this limit the time that a set of patches can be put in place. An appropriate license is already in place on another server but unfortunately the migration can not be done in a reasonable time. To address the most pressing, we must find the way to override the limit imposed by SQL Server Express. Shrinkage, aliasing, file splitting, index changes, all of these were attempted without success. Suggestions?

Comment: not a programming question

Answer (score 2):

Since the 10GB limit is *per database* you can use the following trick to split the data among several databases. *Warning*: people with strong DB beliefs please close your eyes now :-)

- Move some tables to other database, choosing a set of tables than doesn't break foreign key constraints.
- For each table create a view with the same name in the original database like this:

  ```
  create view TableName as
    select * from TheOtherDB..TableName
  ```

In this way you use the view as the table and you don't have to change a single query, SQL Server allows `INSERT`, `UPDATE`and `DELETE` on that type of views as if they were a table, but the data is stored in the other DB.

Of course after you migrate to the new server you should move the data back to one database.

Comment: Great, short and very accurate. Should I detail the procedure followed? Thanks a lot Alberto Martinez. That is the perfect method to help us to prepare and accomplish migration process.